# Gray out a range of days in Sharepoint calendar

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint, calendar, sharepoint-designer

We were able to grayout one day but not a range or multiple ranges
Please see the photo to see what we've got using the below code, and also please identify which areas we can edit if we need to implement this in multiple script editors :

The grayout needs to be done for the following ranges:

Monday 13 January and ends on Wednesday 8 April 2020

Tuesday 21 April and ends on Friday 22 May 2020

Tuesday 2 June and ends on Friday 31 July 2020

Thursday 1 October and ends on Monday 21 December 2020

Thanks for your help in advance folks

```
<style>
        td[date="12/25/2019"] {
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomizeCalendarEvents, "SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js");
        function CustomizeCalendarEvents() {
            //Month Calendar View
            SP.UI.ApplicationPages.SummaryCalendarView.prototype.renderGrids_Old =
                SP.UI.ApplicationPages.SummaryCalendarView.prototype.renderGrids;
            SP.UI.ApplicationPages.SummaryCalendarView.prototype.renderGrids =
                function SP_UI_ApplicationPages_SummaryCalendarView$renderGrids($p0) {
                    this.renderGrids_Old($p0);
                    //alert(document.getElementById("WPQ2_nav_header").innerText);
                    if (document.getElementById("WPQ2_nav_header").innerText == "December 2019") {
                        var css = 'table.ms-acal-month tr:nth-child(9) td:nth-child(4){background-color: #CCCCCC;}',
                            head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                            style = document.createElement('style');

                        head.appendChild(style);

                        style.type = 'text/css';
                        style.title = 'MSCustom';
                        if (style.styleSheet) {
                            // This is required for IE8 and below.
                            style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
                        } else {
                            style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('style[title="MSCustom"]').remove();                           
                    }
                };
        }
    </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference. We just add the day ranges into the "dateRanges" variable in code. Like: "1/13/2020-4/8/2020".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomizeCalendarEvents, "SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js");
function CustomizeCalendarEvents() {
    //Month Calendar View
    SP.UI.ApplicationPages.SummaryCalendarView.prototype.renderGrids_Old = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.SummaryCalendarView.prototype.renderGrids;
    SP.UI.ApplicationPages.SummaryCalendarView.prototype.renderGrids = function SP_UI_ApplicationPages_SummaryCalendarView$renderGrids($p0) {
        this.renderGrids_Old($p0);
        grayoutDate();
    };
}
function grayoutDate(){
    var dateRanges=["1/13/2020-4/8/2020","4/21/2020-5/22/2020","6/2/2020-7/31/2020","10/1/2020-12/21/2020"];
    $(".ms-acal-summary-dayrow").each(function(){
        $(this).children("td").each(function(i){
            var date=new Date($(this).attr("date"));
            for(var j=0;j<dateRanges.length;j++){
                var dateRange=dateRanges[j].split("-");
                if(date>=new Date(dateRange[0])&&date<=new Date(dateRange[1])){
                    $(this).css("background-color","#CCCCCC");
                    $(this).closest("tr").next().children().eq(i).css("background-color","#CCCCCC");
                }
            }

        });
    });   
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that will only work for December, we need to to the grayout for the following ranges,                                                                                                     Monday 13 January and ends on Wednesday 8 April 2020
Tuesday 21 April and ends on Friday 22 May 2020
Tuesday 2 June and ends on Friday 31 July 2020
Thursday 1 October and ends on Monday 21 December 2020